# What is the difference between new ObjectId() and new ObjectId and ObjectId()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose that I have this definition at the beginning of a file:

```
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
```

Which one should you prefer and why?

```
// 1 
new ObjectId;  

// 2
new ObjectId();

// 3
ObjectId();
```

The official document suggests using `new ObjectId`. For me `new ObjectId()` feels more natural but each of them generates a new ObjectId and I have seen examples for each of them in SO's questions and answers.

> http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types-objectid-js

**Update:**
Let me clear this: I know why and how to use a new operator in JavaScript, I just want to find out is there any significant difference when `new` is used for ObjectID generation. (The function behaves different, throws an error, etc ...)

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Description) has a good explanation of the `new` operator (and why constructors will most likely act a bit weird if you call them without it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is absolutely zero difference between these instantiations. Let me go through each way and explain how it works:

- `new ObjectId` - This is completely fine and does the same thing as `new ObjectId();` because you can instantiate without parentheses if the constructor does not take any arguments, see [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) on the `new` operator
- `new ObjectId()` - This is the "standard" way to instantiate an object and is equivalent to `new ObjectId`
- `ObjectId()` - This is the **exact same** as the above two. This is because of the line in the [source code](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/1.0-branch/lib/bson/objectid.js):

  ```
  if(!(this instanceof ObjectID)) return new ObjectID(id);
  ```

  The above code does the following:

  a. `!(this instanceof ObjectID)` - Checks if `this` is an instance of `ObjectID`. This is **only true** if the constructor is called with `new` where `this` will refer to the current instance, or else `this` will be `window` or `undefined` depending on if you are in strict mode.

  b. `return new ObjectID(id)` - If the constructor *is not* called with `new`, then the function will return `new ObjectID(id)`. That means if you call `ObjectId()` in your example, the function will detect this and return `new ObjectID(id)` (or if `id` is not given, `new ObjectID()`) so it is exactly the same as the above two options.

In conclusion, there's no functional difference, it's just up to however you like to write it. There's no reason to prefer one over the other functionally.

---

Note: `ObjectID` and `ObjectId` are the same thing. The source code states: `var ObjectId = ObjectID;`.

Comment: thanks for elaborating this. The only thing that is not valid, at least after testing mongodb in Node.JS is that ObjectId is invalid. Mongodb package `"mongodb": "^2.2.30"` here is only accepting `ObjectID` (ID in capital letters): Otherwise you could get this error:  `node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:429  throw err ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined`. As you said, both syntaxes work `ObjectID()` or `new ObjectID()`

Comment: @JuniorM I was talking about Mongoose, not general MongoDB. Mongoose exposes ObjectId and ObjectID.